# How to call a PHP file using AJAX from many webpages?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I made a personal framework for myself. I added this ajax script in every webpage of my website `include`ing a single PHP file in every webpage.

I put this script in my add.php file, :

```
    function demo(str) 
    {
        if (str.length==0){  return; }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        } 
        else { 
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","bin.php?tid="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    } 

    demo('astring');
```

The problem is, this ajax-called PHP file (bin.php) is in my folder `root/a/bin.php`

While my webpages are in many folder and subfolder like `root/a`, `root/b`, `root/a/a1`, `root/b/b1/b2` so many..

I can't add this ajax calling script on everpage separately.. That's why I included a PHP-file on every webpage, so later I only need to change this PHP-file, to make changes in every webpage.

This ajax works on some webpages only (due to AJAX-Called file's path problem), can you please suggest me a solution to this ajax script so it can work from every webpage?

Comment: why dont you use absolute path to include your php file ?

Comment: How are you including your other files? By using `autoloader` or `include`, `require`?

Comment: @Sachyn i don't think absolute path will work..!!
#Rahil using Include and Require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate absolute path with this code

```
var url = location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + '/your_path/' + "bin.php?tid="+str;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative site-path:

```
function demo(str) 
{
    if (str.length==0){  return; }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else { 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/a/bin.php?tid="+str,true); // links to http(s)://<domain>/a/bin.....
    xmlhttp.send();
} 

demo('astring');
```

Comment: Cute, but will give problems in a development enviroment while using virtual directories/subfolders/..

Comment: Does the question require an answer that works in development environments?

Comment: thanks , but i think i need to use the absolute Path.

Comment: Use this line instead:
xmlhttp.open("GET","http ://domain.tld/a/bin.php?tid="+str,true); // links to http(s)://<domain>/a/bin.....